# AFNetworking 3.0 setSharedImageCache missing

Tags: objective-c, image, caching, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I'm migrating an Objective-C project that is using AFNetworking 2.x to AFNetworking 3.0.

When the app starts, the image cache was cleaned using this property:

```
[UIImageView setSharedImageCache:nil]
```

The point is that I can't find similar function in AFNetworking 3.0. Is there any other way to get this in the new version?

I will be very thankful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: What do you do with images? You need to cache them longer that session on only per app session?

Comment: I only need them per app session, so when the user closes the app and open it again, the image cache needs to be cleaned.

Comment: look at my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any more to `setSharedImageCache`.

import header

```
#import <AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>
```

and set image

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
```

Or, with a placeholder image displayed while the image is being downloaded:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```